# What does the accuracy rating on armor in the cRPG mod of Mount & Blade: Warband do?

Tags: mount-and-blade

I am curious if anyone is aware of the meaning of the "accuracy" rating on armor pieces in the [cRPG mod](http://www.c-rpg.net)? Is it a bonus? A detriment? Does it help or hurt your bow/crossbow accuracy? The wiki is very unclear on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some friendly in game individuals, I determined what "accuracy" is as determined by armor. It is a "glitch/typo/bug" that displays the word "accuracy" where "leg armor" is intended.